# Bypass CSS "Universal Selector * Reset"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I've been comisioned to write landing pages for a website.

Here's the problem: the original developer(s) added a "Universal Selector * Reset" in the main css file:

```
* { //Universal Selector '*' Reset
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and then built the site styles around it.

Unfortunately, this is requiring alot of code to work around on Tables, Lists, Headings, Etc..

**The Question is:** Is there any way to bypass the selector for an individual object(table, list, etc) or even for the page in general(aside from not including the css file)?

**Edit:** Some people were confused by my question.  By bypass I mean to ignore the asterisk selector rather than override it...  Also note that I am trying to minimize on extra code.

**Edit 2:** here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x59GM/1/) that illustrates my problem.
Note: "padding: initial;" dosen't seem to be working.

Comment: why wouldnt you just use `table,list { margin: 1em; padding 1em;}`?

Comment: have you tried overriding it using something like `* { margin: initial; padding: initial; }`?

Comment: Wouldn't just supplying a more specific selector do just that? `table { margin: 10px; }`. The point, surely, is to eliminate differences in default styling between browsers; why you would want to revert to that inconsistent styling I have no idea.

Comment: Is the issue that you can't override anything, or that you'd like a better way to override EVERYTHING?

Comment: u can just go * table {new style } to overwrite

Comment: http://webplantmedia.com/css/2010/03/how-to-override-a-css-class/

Comment: @KingKing The [`initial` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial) isn't supported in IE, and may not actually do what is required here, since it means different things on different elements (e.g. `border-color` has an initial value of the current color, as specified by `color`).

Comment: If my current answer doesn't suffice then could you please further elaborate on what you're after, I might've misunderstood you.

Comment: @Nit I think you understood but padding:initial isn't working for what I need. Also the styles file is not under my control.

Comment: I added a jsFiddle to illustrate my problem.

Comment: ignoring it and changing it back to the original/default values are the same.

Comment: @KingKing At least in chrome "padding:inital" is not changing it back to the original/default values. See jsFiddle above.

Comment: I'll expand my answer to explain the differences.

Comment: @BenA.Noone I did not mean `initial` works, in fact I tried it and I know it does not work in any browsers (at least for padding). Here is how you can use script to ignore the `*` rule [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/x59GM/2/)

Comment: @KingKing wow that is a cool script. You should really post it as an answer.

Comment: @BenA.Noone I of course would have posted it as an answer if you tagged such as `javascript` or `jquery` for your question, so I just posted it as a reference in case you want to use script to solve the problem.

Comment: @KingKing good point. I'm not against using javascript to solve the problem. Edited ;)

Comment: I still don't follow why you *want* to revert to the browser default style. Why not just define your own base styles for the relevant element types, which will be consistent and predictable.

Comment: It's a landing page so I'm trying to optimise on page load speed. If I redefined everything I wanted to use it would slow down the browser.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Any* other selector is more specific than the `*` selector and will thus override it's effects.
See the following [**sample Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gc4AT/).

So therefore if you, for example, want to restore the paddings on a <table> you can simply do

```
table {
    padding: initial;
}
```

If this doesn't quite tickle your fancy you can instead fine-tune your asterisk selector to ignore elements of your choosing:

```
*:not(table) {
    [...]
}
```

**Appendix:**
As may come unexpected for many, setting a property and then using `initial` on it with a more specific selector doesn't necessarily reverse the setting.
Compare [**a reset to initial value (second image below)**](http://jsfiddle.net/jJwaa/) to [**an unstyled example (first image below)**](http://jsfiddle.net/6frKe/) (depending on your browser the result may differ):

Unstyled:
[image: Unstyled sample]

Reset:
[image: Reset sample]

This is because [the initial value](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade/#initial-value) (defined in the CSS spec) of the property may differ from your browser's default value for the element.

Comment: I will ask the site maintainer to place some "nots" on the asterisk. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can't nullify (ignore) values that are already in the cascade; you have to either modify the rule that introduced the value or override it with another value.

```
* {
    margin: initial;
    padding: initial;
}
```

(Kudos King King) reverts those properties to their initial values, but doesn't reapply the browser's default styles for those elements. (Those styles were overridden earlier and are "lost".) But that's expected. :)

`initial` is the "first" value for a property, before any rules are applied. **Each property** has an initial value defined in the CSS specs.

```
margin  = auto
padding = 0
```

The browser's "default" styles are very different — they're actual style rules applied before author stylesheets. They're written to imitate how pre-CSS browsers displayed certain elements.

```
ul { padding-left: 40px; list-style: disc; … }
```

These are arbitrary — there are no CSS "defaults" for how a list should look. So if you want per-element defaults it's probably best to [write your own](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but this didn't work(at least in chrome). See Nit's answer for an explaination of why.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you wanted to "keep" browser defaults. Just remember -- browser default styles are arbitrary and unknown, so you're better off just writing your own element-specific styles at the start.