# Use the CSS Universal Selector '*' with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I've been asked to write a sample script that will make use of the CSS's universal selector. How do I do it? I know that this is [the universal selector in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127657/bypass-css-universal-selector-reset):

```
 * { //Universal Selector '*' to set/reset property values
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 class="example" style="padding:50px;" >A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p>Click the button to activate the universal selector.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.margin = 0;
    document.body.style.padding = 0;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

On click, the button should reset all margins and paddings of elements to 0. But instead, it does it for the body only.

Clarification: Specifically, I need a javascript method that sets all margins and paddings for all elements to 0.

Comment: What you want to do ?

Comment: can you explain what try to do?

Comment: There isn't such thing as a *"reset selector"*, do you mean using the universal selector to "reset" the CSS of an element meaning doing `margin: 0, padding: 0` in his case?

Comment: What do you mean by "script"? Do you mean JavaScript? What do you mean by "reset selector"? Do you mean a CSS rule? Normally, CSS rules are not defined by scripts, but in a CSS stylesheet. What do you want to reset? Do you want to reset the user agent stylesheet, which is what, for example, adds margins to the body, which you can do by saying `body { margin: 0; }`? Do you want to reset all properties, or just certain ones? Do you want to reset CSS styles that apply to some higher-level element and are being inherited?

Comment: I need to write  a sample script to defines a reset selector. Sorry for being unclear, just "sample" script. I don't know how is this done in javascript.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: Yes, I mean that. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @torazaburo: Specifically, I need a javascript method that sets all margins and paddings for all elements to 0.

Comment: @dummie Please add that clarification to your question. It would be also be helpful if you could provide some sample HTML/CSS and show the behavior you expect after the reset. Do you want all margins and paddings on all elements to be set to zero forever?

Comment: @torazaburo, yes zero forever. Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple sample to start with and it iterates through the body's elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 class="example" style="padding:50px;" >A heading with class="example"</h2>
<p>Click the button to activate the universal selector.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var els = document.body.querySelectorAll("*");
  for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    els[i].style.margin = 0;
    els[i].style.padding = 0;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use jQuery's `$('*')` or `document.querySelectorAll("*")`.

Comment: I think you mean `document.querySelectorAll("*")`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I appreciate a jsfiddle.